# App Registration in Azure AD for different enviroments---Best practices

Tags: azure-active-directory, registration, environment

I am looking for best practices for registering App in Azure AD for different environments like DEV, TEST, UAT and PROD

I have an PROD subscription and non PROD subscription both of which are tied to our Corporate Azure AD
Now to have an application in different environments and have Corporate users have access to it during Development as well has end users, what are the best practices?

I am thinking of creating of Directories for different envs and then have the app registration in each of these directory and add corporate users as guest users to this. So app registration is in this Directory while the workloads are in the Corporate Directory

Is it a good practice?

Comment: What is your concern if you register your application in your corporate Directory?

Comment: For DEV registration, Developers need access to register the app and edit the apps but at the same time they should no be able to see and edit other apps. Not sure if that kid oif granular would be possible if we register all apps in a single directory

Comment: I will confirm this for you.

Comment: Thanks Tony. One challenge I faced earlier while using the approach i describe earlier (having a seperate directory for App registration) was that i could not connect to KeyVault since the KeyVault was in a subscription associated with a different Directory and the app registration was in a different

Comment: @ravishanker - what did you ever do for this situation? I am in a similar situation where I need a Dev, QA and Prod and I have to restrict access to users per each environment. I am thinking making three app registrations as the solution but didn't know if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed with Azure support engineer that we can not restrict users to access the apps, the apps will be visible to all users. But only the owners and admin can edit the apps.

[image]

If the user is not the owner of the app(also not the admin), he/she will be unable to edit the app.
[image]